# IPython Notebook - Log messages from Scikit Parallel

Tags: ipython, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have a script that uses scikit-learn's parallel features (implemented by the joblib library).  Typically I run it with higher verbosity, so that I can monitor the progress:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator, params, cv=5, n_jobs=4, verbose=50)
```

When using a normal Python console, the messages from the `Parallel` library get printed to the console as they occur, like so:

`[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done   4 jobs       | elapsed:   32.8s
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done   2 jobs       | elapsed:   33.7s`

However, when I'm running the script in an IPython notebook, it looks like these messages are getting buffered while the job runs, and only outputs after it has completed or I terminate the kernel.

Is there any way to get it to display in real time in the notebook?

Comment: Seems like there are a couple of related questions, but none with an answer that works for my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430827/printing-to-main-stdout-in-ipython-notebook-from-other-parallel-engines?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289168/printing-to-stdout-in-ipython-parallel-processes?rq=1